# Validation failed for query for method public, spring jpa?

Tags: java, sql, spring, jpa

I am creating an api to query from the DB and return the result.

This is the request

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/config", params = { "appCode", "appVersion" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<AppConfig> getConfig(@RequestParam(value = "appCode", required = true) String appCode,
        @RequestParam(value = "appVersion", required = true) String appVersion) {
    return configRepository.findByCodeAndVersion(appCode, appCode);
}
```

The table class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "app_config")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class AppConfig {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(columnDefinition = "serial")
private long id;
@Column(name = "app_code", nullable = false)
private String appCode;
@Column(name = "app_name", nullable = false)
private String appName;
@Column(name = "api_url", nullable = true)
private String apiUrl;
@Column(name = "db_name", nullable = true)
private String dbName;
@Column(name = "app_version", nullable = false)
private String appVersion;
}
```

The repository where I am having custom query

```
@Repository
public interface AppConfigRepository extends CrudRepository<AppConfig, Long> {

@Query("SELECT n FROM AppConfig WHERE n.appCode = ?1 and n.appVersion = ?2")
List<AppConfig> findByCodeAndVersion(String appCode, String appVersion);
}
```

On running the application I get the exception

```
Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.api.repository.AppConfigRepository.findByCodeAndVersion(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)!
```

Comment: You should be getting additional output in your stack trace. That said, however, it doesn't seem like there's any need for your `@Query` annotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the alias `n` after the entity name `AppConfig` in the query, it should be like:

```
@Query("SELECT n FROM AppConfig n WHERE n.appCode = ?1 and n.appVersion = ?2")
List<AppConfig> findByCodeAndVersion(String appCode, String appVersion);
```

You can also use named parameter inside the query string like this:

```
@Query("SELECT n FROM AppConfig n WHERE n.appCode = :appCode and n.appVersion = :appVersion")
List<AppConfig> findByCodeAndVersion(String appCode, String appVersion);
```

And a query like this can be handled by Spring data query methods, just make sure to rename the method to use the field names of the entity:

```
List<AppConfig> findByAppCodeAndAppVersion(String appCode, String appVersion);
```

Comment: thanx this works but now I am not getting any results while data exist in DB.                               Hibernate: select appconfig0_.id as id1_0_, appconfig0_.api_url as api_url2_0_, appconfig0_.app_code as app_code3_0_, appconfig0_.app_name as app_name4_0_, appconfig0_.app_version as app_vers5_0_, appconfig0_.db_name as db_name6_0_ from app_config appconfig0_ where appconfig0_.app_code=? and appconfig0_.app_version=?

Comment: Are you sure about the `and` condition? or the passed parameters?

Comment: yes this is the URL http://localhost:9090/api/v1/config?appCode=MANDL_LIVE&appVersion=12.0 I am hitting. Querying in the DB I get the results

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
@Query("SELECT FROM AppConfig n WHERE n.appCode = :x and n.appVersion = :y")
List<AppConfig> findByCodeAndVersion(@Param("x")String appCode,@Param("y") String appVersion);
```

or you can use directly the method:

```
List<AppConfig> findByAppCodeAndAppVersion(String appCode,String appVersion);
```

Comment: Tips: Try to put some details about your solution code only answer is not SO standard.